# Is signal driven I/O actually deprecated by epoll in practice under linux?

Tags: c, linux, performance, io, portability

According to the book *[The Linux Programming Interface](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ps2SH727eCIC&pg=PA1328&lpg=PA1328&dq=advantage%20%22Signal%20driven%22%20I/O%20linux&source=bl&ots=kMEfw7yPu7&sig=xpbprLzyqQy6K6Y2kA6OnVhcajs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3t6j7qOrcAhVFhuAKHZy1C2UQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=advantage%20%22Signal%20driven%22%20I%2FO%20linux&f=false)*:

> epoll provides a number of advantages over signal driven I/O.

Can we safely say:

**Signal driven I/O has actually been deprecated by epoll in practice under linux?**

Comment: If you were going to use signal-driven I/O in a new application you would probably need to come up with justification for that.

Comment: I think it would be fair to say that signal-driven I/O was always a horrible and poorly-supported kludge and Unix would really rather you use _any other method_ of multiplexing I/O, even plain old `select`.  However, there have always been situations where using signals to some extent was unavoidable (e.g. multiplexing wait-for-I/O with wait-for-child-process) and I dunno if epoll, in particular, has resolved all of them, but it sure would be nice if it had.

Comment: Let me suggest you rephrase the question as "If you are not concerned with portability, and are making full use of Linux-specific APIs such as `epoll`, `signalfd`, etc., are there any remaining situations where you still have to use an asynchronous signal handler for something?"  That is a reasonably scoped, non-opinion question.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that "signal driven I/O" is referring to the POSIX `aio` (asynchronous I/O) facility, using the aio_sigevent notification method, then it is perhaps fair to say that most networking applications desiring asynchronous operation will favor `epoll` over `aio`. Deprecation may be a bit strong.

I do want to point out that the `aio` facility outshines `epoll` for disk I/O. The `aiocb` structure allows an offset for a `aio_write` or `aio_read` command to be specified for the operation. So, multiple file I/O operations can be occurring in parallel over many different offsets in the file. Tradition file descriptor I/O with `epoll` would typically be serialized as stream operations where the next operation continues where the previously completed operation left off.